# simple 1 layer area chart in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create a simple area chart in bokeh (1 layer) 
My attempt

```
df_example = pd.DataFrame(data=  [['01-01-2018',10],['02-01-2018', 5 ], ['03-01-2018',7]], columns = ['date', 'value'] )

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=400, x_range = df_example['date'])

p.Area(df_example, x='date', y='value') 

show(p)
```

I get an error

```
 AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'Area'
```

Is the Area chart seems to be not available in bokeh anymore

**Can anybody demonstrate how to get this type of chart please?**

Comment: What else have you tried? The error message is telling you everything you need to know about your current efforts.

Comment: @PMende Why -1? What is wrong with this question ?? I haven't found any single example in the documentation related to the newest version of bokeh for such a  case. no such examples on stackoverflow either. There are some stacked areas examples more complicated, but not for just 1 layer

Comment: Because it doesn't feel like you've put all that much effort into resolving the issue on your own. You encountered an `AttributeError`. That has a very specific meaning. What made you think that `figure` objects had an `Area` method to begin with? Why doesn't it? The answer is that this functionality was deprecated. Did you make attempts to build up this style of chart on your own, or look for other pre-built options to achieve what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bokeh recently added a `varea_stack` glyph method:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y1=[1, 2, 4, 3, 4],
    y2=[1, 4, 2, 2, 3],
))
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.varea_stack(['y1', 'y2'], x='x', color=("grey", "lightgrey"), source=source)

show(p)
```

[image]